# How table_alias can be used in the lateral view clause

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-lateral-view.html#examples

It provides an example as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE person (id INT, name STRING, age INT, class INT, address STRING);
INSERT INTO person VALUES
    (100, 'John', 30, 1, 'Street 1'),
    (200, 'Mary', NULL, 1, 'Street 2'),
    (300, 'Mike', 80, 3, 'Street 3'),
    (400, 'Dan', 50, 4, 'Street 4');

SELECT * FROM person
    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(ARRAY(30, 60)) tableName AS c_age  ---how can tableName be used
    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(ARRAY(40, 80)) AS d_age;
+------+-------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|  id  | name  |  age  | class  |  address  | c_age  | d_age  |
+------+-------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
| 100  | John  | 30    | 1      | Street 1  | 30     | 40     |
| 100  | John  | 30    | 1      | Street 1  | 30     | 80     |
| 100  | John  | 30    | 1      | Street 1  | 60     | 40     |
| 100  | John  | 30    | 1      | Street 1  | 60     | 80     |
| 200  | Mary  | NULL  | 1      | Street 2  | 30     | 40     |
| 200  | Mary  | NULL  | 1      | Street 2  | 30     | 80     |
| 200  | Mary  | NULL  | 1      | Street 2  | 60     | 40     |
| 200  | Mary  | NULL  | 1      | Street 2  | 60     | 80     |
| 300  | Mike  | 80    | 3      | Street 3  | 30     | 40     |
| 300  | Mike  | 80    | 3      | Street 3  | 30     | 80     |
| 300  | Mike  | 80    | 3      | Street 3  | 60     | 40     |
| 300  | Mike  | 80    | 3      | Street 3  | 60     | 80     |
| 400  | Dan   | 50    | 4      | Street 4  | 30     | 40     |
| 400  | Dan   | 50    | 4      | Street 4  | 30     | 80     |
| 400  | Dan   | 50    | 4      | Street 4  | 60     | 40     |
| 400  | Dan   | 50    | 4      | Street 4  | 60     | 80     |
+------+-------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

There is a `tableName` in `LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(ARRAY(30, 60)) tableName AS c_age`, it is a table alias. How can it be used?